# Why most fft library use Complex struct instead of two arrays for imaginary and real parts

Tags: c, fft

I am asking this because generally, input data such as audio signals are continous array block, and before feeding them into fft routine, one has to convert structure of data from array to array of Complex(re, im) using a loop

When input data do not have imaginary part, we could directly assign or use memcpy, this would have saved lot of time.

Comment: Keeping all the parts of a single data point seems really important, and keeping them separate is asking for one part of that data to be ignored.

Are you referring to an input circumstance that has ONLY real data and zero imaginary parts? Or could there be mix-and-match?

Comment: @SteveFriedl, in my use case data points will have only real part, it is acceptable supply 0 filled imaginary array alongside , both will have same size and refer to same pair using index then how they will be missed, next when i do reverse fft, then it will have re and im part both, but it should be handled same way

Comment: Structure Of Arrays style vs Array Of Structures. Sometimes one is better than the other depending on what you're doing. Sounds like the former would be better for you in this case, yes.

Comment: @Shawn I am using raspberry pi gpu_fft, they implemented using Array of Structures. So are you saying that both type of implementation will be equal performance wise? i ask because many library take this route(Array of struct) and i am not sure it is because of "use case" or library implementation required them to be so.

Comment: FFTW has a function that takes one array with the real component and one with the imaginary component. But that is not the solution you are looking for. Instead use the RFFT, which takes a real-valued array as input and produces half the frequency domain. This saves a lot of redundant multiplications by zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why most fft library use Complex struct instead of two arrays for imaginary and real parts

FFT routines that take an array of some complex type rather than an array of reals and an array of imaginaries are generally provided for the convenience of programs written to use complex types. FFT routines that take an array of reals and an array of imaginaries are more common in routines written for high performance (due to the reduced manipulations needed in SIMD instructions and other aspects of a high-performance FFT implementation).

> When input data do not have imaginary part,…

To work with pure-real input data (data that has no imaginary component), you should seek a real-to-complex FFT routine, as this will generally give better performance than using a complex-to-complex FFT routine with the imaginary components set to zeros.

Comment: you said array of re and im will have the better performance, then looks like gpu based popular library like cuda and raspberry implemented them using array of struct is not a good approach?