# x86 intrinsic: 2 float vectors to interleaved

Tags: x86, fft, avx

I have two __mm256 vectors each contains 8 float numbers

```
__mm256 a = {00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07};
__mm256 b = {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};
```

I have to create 2 interleaved vectors:

```
__mm256 c = {00,10,01,11,02,12,03,13};
__mm256 d = {04,14,05,15,06,16,07,17};
```

It seems I need to run:

```
_mm256_unpackhi_ps
_mm256_unpacklo_ps
and then permute.
```

Is there a  faster way ?

The motivation:
All my computation is done separately for real,imag
But I failed to find FFT library that works on non interleaved data.
IPP (intel) and FFTW both have no solution for separated `real,imag` vectors.

Comment: Yes, lane-crossing interleave for a single pair of vectors needs 3 shuffles, I think.  It might be possible to use fewer shuffles but more total instructions by using some blends, like maybe integer shift (`vpsrlq` by 32), 2x vblendps, and then shuffle each of the all-real / all-imag vectors.  But that's probably not worth it on Ice Lake or later, or on Zen.  On Skylake or earlier where all shuffles are port-5 only, it can be better if that's all you're doing, not overlapped with other computation.

Comment: For your FFT use-case, keep looking I think.  [Why most fft library use Complex struct instead of two arrays for imaginary and real parts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72639914) explains that interleaved does suck for FFT, and suggests that struct-of-arrays FFT functions should exist.

Comment: FFTW *does* support the format that you want. They call it [split array format](http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Interleaved-and-split-arrays.html#Interleaved-and-split-arrays) with the planning API described [here](http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Guru-Complex-DFTs.html#Guru-Complex-DFTs)

Comment: You can get both outputs with one `vunpckhps`+`vunpcklps` and two interlane shuffles: https://godbolt.org/z/3x3rxh5P9. If your bottleneck are shuffles instead of memory access, you can consider using `vextractf128` with a memory destination: https://uops.info/html-instr/VEXTRACTF128_M128_YMM_I8.html

Comment: Peter, Homer512, chtz - Thank you very much !